# CSS transition not work properly when render react element in array

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

When render react component in an array with CSS transition, then that array will be re-order and change the style, I found that only elements that go up have transition while the elements go down don't have transition applied. I expect that all elements got styling change after render should have transition remain on them.

Here is the codesandbox for that issue https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-fire-9zrc4

I appreciate any helps. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong key parameter. If the key changes react reorders the whole DOM, breaking animations.
Change `key={opt.name}` in line 6 to `key={i}`

Comment: I assign the key to the unique value of option item to maintain their state before and after the render. Use index as key will work for this case but it will suffer the state of each option